# What are the app file size limitations for different smartphone OSes & carriers?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7

I know the iPhone App Store limits how large an app can be in general and there are also limitations with AT&T over the size it can be to transmit over a data plan vs WiFi. I have no idea what, if any, these limits are for Android apps and what I'm finding online is a mix of different numbers.

Does anyone know these numbers definitively? The Android game I'm porting is in the 20-30MB range and we'd like to know if we need to further reduce its size.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is 225MB (not sure about further carrier limits)

Comment: I've seen apps of sizes around 200MB.

Comment: Can't tell if you are asking about Android specifically or all...  The iPhone has a hard 2G limit on the app size.  The largest app I have on my iOS is 600M+.  Rage HD is 750M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Android

The maximum size for the market is 50 MB, and can be downloaded over-the-air. Third party stores can have whatever size files they want. The 50 MB limit is only on the .apk file size, it is possible to load content or other data after the app loads, only limited by the storage on the users device.

### iOS

The maximum size for distribution over cell networks is 20 MB.  The maximum size for an app over WiFi or iTunes is 2 GB.  It is possible to load content or other data after the app loads, only limited by the storage on the users device.

### Windows Phone 7

The maximum size for over-the-air is 20 MB. The maximum file size is 225 MB

Comment: Just for clarification: over-the-air means downloading the app on the phone directly using the 3G connection, as opposed to downloading the app on your computer and then transferring it to your phone.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for that edit, I researched on Google a bit, but I was not sure one way or the other with regards to iOS, so I didn't put anything.

Answer (score 1):

The limit on iPhone apps for transmitting over 3G is 20MB (although that'll take a long time to download, so you definitely want to be much smaller than that.)

I don't know what the overall app size limit is (ie. how big can an app be to download over a wired connection?) because I behave as if the wireless limit is the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 24, 2010, the largest apk file you are able to upload is 25MB.  I don't believe it has changed.

Comment: Incorrect. The current size limit on the android store is 50 MB, and that is only for the Android Market; third party stores can have whatever size they want.

Answer (score 0):

As of 5 March 2012, the limit for Android has been upped to 4GB from 50mb.
As of 7 March 2012, the limit for OTA (over-the-air) downloads for iOS was raised to 50mb from 20mb. iOS max limit for non-OTA downloads remains 2GB.

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application) on iOS changes, specifically.

Comment: Android is still not as rosy as it sounds. Google will now host up to 4GB of data for you, and calculate it as part of your app size on the store, but there is still a 50MB APK limit and you need to integrate their "Expansion Download Service" into your code. You also can't sideload and it's not compatible with other stores.